# Generic C++ copy between objects that support copy construction and those that don't

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

A long story short, I'm working on a container that can contain either copy constructable objects, or those that don't. Something like:

```
using AllocTraits = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>;
template <typename T>
void foo(T *to T *from, size_t n, Alloc alloc) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    AllocTraits::construct(alloc, to++, *from++);
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that my `T` can support either copy constructable classes or moveable classes. So, I moved to a slightly different approach:

```
using AllocTraits = std::allocator_traits<Alloc>;
template <typename T>
void foo(T *to T *from, size_t n, Alloc alloc) {
  auto mov_to = std::make_move_iterator(to);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    AllocTraits::construct(alloc, mov_to++, *from++);
  }
}
```

But this will call `T::(T&&)`, when I'd rather call `T::T(const T&)` if the type supports it.

How can I write `foo` so that it will call `T::T(const T&)` as a default, but move to `T::T(T&&)` otherwise?

Comment: `std::make_move_iterator` is for where you move *from*, not *to*. I.e. `auto mov_from = std::make_move_iterator(from)`;

Answer (score 0):

Just use `enable_if`:

```
template <typename T, typename Alloc, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void foo(T *to, T *from, size_t n, Alloc alloc) {
  // for movables
}

template <typename T, typename Alloc, std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void foo(T *to, T *from, size_t n, Alloc alloc) {
  // for copy-constructables
}
```